# Sum different unknown values from multiple tables in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having the following Issue and don't get the right formula. I don't even know, if it is possible.

I'm having three tables with different values. I want to calculate and sum up, which value appears how many times in all three tables. I don't really know the value when starting the process, so it should count the following: How often are which values shown in the tables.

[Find a example of the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNSF3.png)

so, the result should tell me, that overall, there are 3 values (a,b,c) and each value has a total quantity of 60.

[Here, you'll find the result I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mie4z.png)

I want to do that calculation with google spreadsheet, but I really don't get any solution.

Can somebody help? Thank you already in advance.

Comment: I've read your question, looked at the links, and I still have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use query function:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A1:B;'Sheet2'!A2:B;'Sheet3'!A2:B},"select Col2, sum(Col1) group by Col2")
```